# Insert scoped into style tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to insert the scoped attribute into the style tags of a website wether the tag is in the header or the body?

Tried this and did not work:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery("style").attr('scoped','true');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It all seems to be working for me in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kingcodefish/5n8mhv28/

It should be noted that `scoped` is bad practice as the `<style>` tag is only intended to be used in the `<head>`, already nullifying any way to use `scoped`. On top of that, it only works in Firefox 21 and later.

I know it may seem obvious, but be sure you're linking in jQuery correctly and you're using a Firefox version that supports `scoped`.